# How can I get some of a posts meta data whilst it is still inserting?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to make a function where a child post of a certain post type inherits the same title and slug as its parent. I'm using WP Types to define my post types and their relationships. But I'm having trouble with the below code:

```
function copy_parent_post_title( $post_id ) {

    $new_post = get_post($post_id);

    if($new_post->post_type == 'carnews-adverts') {

        $parent_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id', true );
        $parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);
        $post_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($parent_title);

        $post_update = array(
            'ID'           => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $parent_title,
            'post_name' => $post_slug
        );

        remove_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );
        wp_update_post( $post_update );
        add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );

    }

}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'copy_parent_post_title' );
```

The problem is this line:

```
$parent_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id', true );
```

I presume it is because at this point the post's meta data hasn't been inserted into the database yet? If so how can I achieve what I want by accessing the get_post_meta upon inserting a post?

Thanks

Comment: Why not `$parent_title = get_the_title($post_id);` or `$parent_title = $new_post->post_title;`?

Isn't $post_id the ID of the parent post?

Comment: No, $post_id is the current post being inserted, it's not the parent post.

Comment: I think to access the '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id' that is begin added by WP Types, you need to look in the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

I think to access the '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id' that is being added by WP Types, you need to look in the $_POST array. However, WP Types might call add_post_meta() after calling wp_insert_post(). In this case the meta data won't be present if you hook into wp_insert_post.

Instead, hook your function into add_post_meta:

```
function copy_parent_post_title( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {

    $new_post = get_post($post_id);

    if (($new_post->post_type == 'carnews-adverts') &&
        ($meta_key == '_wpcf_belongs_carnews_id')) {

        $parent_id = $meta_value;

        $parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);

        // ... Rest of your function
    }
}
add_action( 'add_post_meta', 'copy_parent_post_title', 10, 3 );
```

This may be completely wrong as I barely ever use Wordpress.